# Geolocation in android webview works only if i allowed location permission in the browser

Tags: javascript, java, android, geolocation

When i install my webview app on phone it doesn't access the location even after the location permission for the app is given. But when i open my website in chrome after the permission is give it also works in my webview.

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);




 webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(final String origin, final GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
            callback.invoke(origin, true, true);
            super.onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(origin, callback);
        }
```

}

Comment: WebView == Chrome !?